# In which module the ngModel is defined.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As every directive, component and controller has its own module, In which module the ngModel, ngRepeat and other inbuilt directives are defined.?

Comment: You can find more information https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 1):

You can find built-in directives definition in Angular.js source code:

- [ngModel](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L1323)
- [ngRepeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L433)

These built-in directive are the part of `ng` module that is

> loaded by default when an AngularJS application is started

as specified by the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng#module-installation).